# Failing to deploy flask app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been working on this for quite some time now and all of a sudden when I run `eb deploy` to deploy a newer version I get this error in red:

> ERROR: Environment named *** is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready.

Comment: Also have now tried to terminate the environment via `eb terminate` and I get the very same error!

Comment: This [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=132082) here helped me solve the issue... For anyone who may come across this in the future...